# variance from xtpoisson in comparison to variance from xtlogit

Tags: variance, stata, poisson-distribution, multilevel-analysis, logit

I have a binary variable indicating whether a c-section was carried out or not.   C-section is more than 10% prevalent in the population. I want to model predictors of c-section.  Initially I had used an `xtlogit` model in Stata to model this. The xtlogit command runs a multilevel model. I need a multilevel model because the outcome may be clustered at the hospital level, so I use a random intercept to allow for this.  However, the odds ratios that are returned seem problematic. In some instances, an OR of >500 is given back for some explanatory variables. This is probably because the OR is overestimating the true underlying risk. This happens when a violation of the "rare outcome" assumption occurs (because c-section is >10% in the population - the assumptionis violated here). http://www.bmj.com/content/348/bmj.f7450.full?ijkey=NHT1YVsoX1RCm8r&keytype=ref

Instead, I ran an `xtpoisson` model which gives risk estimates that are much more plausible. I used a poisson model because I read on this post that it is appropriate model binary outcomes in this manner when a RR is required. [Poisson regression to estimate relative risk for binary outcomes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18595/poisson-regression-to-estimate-relative-risk-for-binary-outcomes)

However, the estimates of variance are now completely different to what was estimated with the `xtlogit`. For example in the `xtlogit` model I calculated a VPC of 30%. This is now 2% from the `xtpoisson`. Should the VPC have changed this much? Which is the more reliable estimate to use?

Comment: If this is not a Stata question, then you should explain to the majority of non-Stata users here what the commands you used do and not presume that it's evident from their names. Even more crucially, what is the response (outcome) variable such that a Poisson model appears an alternative to a logit model? Is that the binary variable mentioned in the first sentence? It doesn't seem surprising that models with very different structure don't give similar results.

Comment: Hi @NickCox. Thank you for suggestions, I have now amended question. Am happy to edit further if required. Apologies for not explaining xt commands and hope the above is clearer.

Comment: Thanks; that should improve the question for those who know more about this.

Comment: You might find Bill's comment [in a related question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/38004/7071) interesting.

Comment: thanks @DimitriyV.Masterov. what did you do in the end? Did you use the poisson for your binary outcome?

Comment: @user2363642 I listened to Bill.